# Handling Ansible Error and Return Specific Value

Tags: ansible

I'm using `ec2_instance_info` module in Ansible to get EC2 instance information including tags and save it in CSV file. But some EC2 instances do not have `backup` tag so the play eventually stopped with error.

How to handle the error so when there is no tag assigned, Ansible should write `NULL` in the the CSV file.

Below is the Ansible playbook:

```yaml
---
- name: ec2_instance_info.yml
  hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  gather_facts: False

  tasks:
  - name: Describe an instance
    ec2_instance_info:
      region: ap-southeast-1
      filters:
        "tag:Name": some_instance
    register: info

  - name: Save output into CSV file
    template:
      src: ec2_instance_info_tpl.j2
      dest: ec2_instance_info.csv
```

Below is the Jinja template:

```
Instance_ID,Instance_Name,Instance_Type,Private_IP,Public_IP,Tag_BU,Tag_Backup
{% for each in info.instances %}
{{each.instance_id}},{{each.tags.Name}},{{each.instance_type}},{{each.private_ip_address}},{{each.public_ip_address}},{{each.tags.bu}},{{each.tags.backup}}
{% endfor %}
```

Below is the error message when running the playbook:

```
Error message: fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "AnsibleUndefinedVariable: 'dict object' has no attribute 'backup'"}
```

Comment: See [default](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#providing-default-values). (And close this question. There are plenty of duplicates here.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try below code:

```
Instance_ID,Instance_Name,Instance_Type,Private_IP,Public_IP,Tag_BU,Tag_Backup
{% for each in info.instances %}
{%   if each.tags.backup is defined and each.tags.backup %}
{{each.instance_id}},{{each.tags.Name}},{{each.instance_type}},{{each.private_ip_address}},{{each.public_ip_address}},{{each.tags.bu}},{{each.tags.backup}}
{%   else %}
{{each.instance_id}},{{each.tags.Name}},{{each.instance_type}},{{each.private_ip_address}},{{each.public_ip_address}},{{each.tags.bu}},NULL
{%   endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: I got this error when run the playbook.

fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "AnsibleError: template error while templating string: tag name expected.

Comment: There is a type with dot (.) in your answer. After removing, I managed to get it working.

Comment: @ChickoBueno yes, sorry for the typo, MAC will add a `.` if you input several white space